# Connect Wall: I Don't Mind

Tags: connect-wall

A Connect Wall is a set of sixteen words/proper nouns/phrases which can be broken into four groups of four related items, where the relationship can be described by another word/proper noun/phrase. The four items defining the relations are themselves related, and that relation is defined by a single word/proper noun/phrase as well. Good luck!

|  |  |  |  |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| CROSS | EATING | FORE | FORCE |
| GUT | HUE | LINE | LONG |
| OX | PAY | PERFORCE | POP |
| PORT | RED | SPOT | TAG |

**HINT**

> OX and PORT are in the same group.

Comment: I can't figure the rest of it out, but this might help other people working on this one: rot13(Cresbepr sbe P/P++ naq Uhr sbe FDY ner obgu cbchyne cebtenzzvat gbbyf.)

Comment: @Sciborg Interestingly, I believe the two you mention are indeed in the same group but for an entirely different reason altogether...! (Unfortunately it's currently the only grouping I'm positive about! The others are proving trickier for me...)

Comment: @Stiv Oh! Lucky coincidence, oops :P

Comment: @Deepthinker101 Use rot13 for spoilers in comments please. Thanks.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

**Group 1**

> Words to which **BOW** can be appended - cross**bow**, long**bow**, ox**bow**, [port **bow**](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/port%20bow#:%7E:text=%3A%20the%20port%20surface%20of%20a,stem%20%E2%80%94distinguished%20from%20starboard%20bow)

**Group 2** (also found by Sciborg, with slight change, thanks to Stiv for one of the words)

> Words which are completed with the addition of **MAN** - e**man**ating, hu**man**e, perfor**man**ce, re**man**d

**Group 3**

> Words associated to **OUT** - [Force-**out**](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/force-out), [pop **out**](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/pop%20out), [tag **out**](https://idioms.thefreedictionary.com/tag+out), [line **out**](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/line%20out)

**Group 4**

> Words associated to **CHECK** - [Fore**check**](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/forecheck), , [pay**check**](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/paycheck), [spot-**check**](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/spot-check), [gut check](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/gut%20check)
>  **NB** Thanks to Jeremy Dover for clarifying the positions of line and gut in groups #3 and #4.

And the word which connects all the groups is

> **Rain** = Rain**bow**, Rain**man**, Rain **out** and [rain**check**](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/rain%20check)

Title (thanks to Stiv for the comment)

> This relates to The Beatles' song [Rain](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rain_(Beatles_song)) which has the line "Rain, I don't mind / Shine, the weather's fine"

Comment: Great job hexomino! The final connection is absolutely what I intended, as are the word for the group associations in the first three groups. Suggest looking at group #3 closer: the connection is actually a little bit more specific (you have two of the members right), and it might help you shuffle the words a bit to get a tighter fourth grouping. Only group #1 is completely correct.

Comment: I wonder if you need rot13(rZNAngvat engure guna sberZNA... Gung jnl nyy bs gung tebhc unir ZNA vafregrq va gur zvqqyr.)

Comment: You might also like to [explain the title](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=cK5G8fPmWeA) :)

Comment: Pretty much there! I think it works a little bit better if you switch rot13(yvar naq thg), but this is close enough for the checkmark! Also a typo in group #4...I think you mean fore instead of force. I did enjoy using FORE, FORCE, and PERFORCE in the same connect wall.

Comment: @JeremyDover Thank you, your suggestion indeed is better (I think I am just less familiar with the expression associated to "gut" which is why I missed it). Loved the fore/force/perforce in this and the Group 1 connections, especially.

Comment: Thanks @Stiv I had a feeling it was a classic song just couldn't remember which one.

Comment: Awesome hexomino...glad you enjoyed!